# AngularJS getting filtered list count from a single filter when multiple filters applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started using angularJS. I'm trying to implement item list using ng-repeat with pagination. Everything works fine except when I filter results. The problem is when there are more results then in fits in the page I don't know how much items in total I get so I can't regenerate pagination data.

To get filtered list count I use this:

```
$scope.filterApplied = function (filteredList, query) {

        $scope.filteredItems =  $filter('filter')(filteredList, query);
        if ($scope.filteredItems != null) {
            $scope.totalItems = filteredList.length;
        }
    };
```

but if I set max items per page to lets say 5 and there are 10 results `$scope.totalItems` is equal to 5.

I need to somehow  get the count of items after applying `filter:query` but before `limitTo:(itemsPerPage*currentPage)` and `$index >= (currentPage -1)*5`.

How do I achieve this?

My ng-repeat part looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in peopleList | filter:query | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | limitTo:(itemsPerPage*currentPage)" ng-if="lastResult($index)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could be able to create a variable for limitTo in the controller and only set it after you get length of filtered list:

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in peopleList | filter:query | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | limitTo:limit" ng-if="lastResult($index)">
```

Controller

```
$scope.limit = ($scope.itemsPerPage*$scope.currentPage);

$scope.filterApplied = function (filteredList, query) {

    $scope.filteredItems =  $filter('filter')(filteredList, query);
      if ($scope.filteredItems != null) {
          $scope.limit=0;
          $scope.totalItems = filteredList.length;
          $scope.limit = ($scope.itemsPerPage*$scope.currentPage);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work as `$scope.totalItems` is equal to the number of items after all filters applied